# Why did TypeScript 2.0 change IteratorResult<K>?

Tags: typescript

Switching from TypeScript 1.8 to 2.0.3 some code implementing an Iterator has started generating a new message:  **error TS2322: Type '{ done: true; }' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult'.  Property 'value' is missing in type '{ done: true; }'.**   While a fix is easy (and backwards compatible) I'd like to understand why it has changed...

At least under TypeScript 1.8, `IteratorResult` was defined with the `value` property optional.   From lib.es6.d.ts for 1.8:

```
interface IteratorResult<T> {
    done: boolean;
    value?: T;
}
```

Under 2.0 the declaration reads:

```
interface IteratorResult<T> {
    done: boolean;
    value: T;
}
```

With strict null checking **off**, the of supplying `{ done: true, value: undefined }` fix is obvious but was there some good reason to make `value` mandatory in 2.0?

UPDATE: I've now discovered that when I **turn on** strict null checking, this gets worse, explicitly using undefined (as above) doesn't work either.   Eventually I resorted to this:

```
return { done: true, value: undefined } as any as IteratorResult<T>;
```

For reference, here's an example of the code generating the error:

```
class HashMapKeyIterable<K,V> implements Iterator<K>, IterableIterator<K> {
    private _bucket: HashMapEntry<K,V>[];
    private _index: number;

    constructor( private _buckets : Iterator<HashMapEntry<K,V>[]> ){
        this._bucket = undefined;
        this._index = undefined;
    }

    [Symbol.iterator]() { return this }

    next():  IteratorResult<K> {
        while (true) {
            if (this._bucket) {
                const i = this._index++;
                if (i < this._bucket.length) {
                    let item = this._bucket[i];
                    return {done: false, value: item.key}
                }
            }
            this._index = 0
            let x = this._buckets.next();
            if (x.done) return {done: true}; // Under TS 2.0 this needs to
            this._bucket = x.value;          // return {done: true: value: undefined};
            }
        }
    }
```

Update:  This now seems like a bug, I've filed issue [11375](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11375) to track.